# AngularJS data bind in ng-bind-html?

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html

Is it possible to bind data of scope variable to a html that is about to bind as ng-bind-html?

ie, I have a

```
html ="<div>{{caption}}</div>";
```

and my angular template look like,

```
<div ng-bind-html="html"></div>
```

the value of scope variable `caption` is set in angular controller.

So, I want to bind data in `{{caption}}`.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: may be you want transclude?
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngTransclude

Comment: Look this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40024415/using-ng-bind-html-and-sce-trustashtml-create-a-string-with-ng-model-binding/40024560#40024560) is similar with your case

Answer (score 21):

You should use `$interpolate` not `$compile`. Write the controller like this:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize'])
  .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$interpolate', function($scope, $interpolate){
   $scope.caption = 'My Caption';
   $scope.html = $interpolate('<div>{{caption}}</div>')($scope);
});
```

Then write the HTML like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-bind-html="html"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Upvoted for suggesting `$interpolate` instead of `$compile`. `$interpolate` returns a string, which is what `$scope.html` needs to be in this case; `$compile` returns a DOM element. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17901134/4192097) gives a great explanation of `$compile` vs. `$interpolate` vs. `$parse`.

Answer (score 7):

You need to compile your HTML snippet, but it is recommended to do that inside the directive.

```js
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($compile){
  $scope.caption = 'My Caption';
  $scope.html = $compile('<div>{{caption}}</div>')($scope);
});
```

```html
<div ng-bind-html="html"></div>
```

Answer (score -3):

What about?

`html = '<div ng-bind="caption"></div>';`