# angular command in ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ng-bind-html

I'm trying to use `$interpolate` and `ng-bind-html` to bind the data of my scope variable to a html string by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25420253/2232900). Now when my scope variable's value is updating the `ng-bind-html` result, its not updating.

I don't want to call `$interpolate` every time that my scope updates.

This is my controller code:

```
$scope.TitleFlag= true;
$scope.HtmlContent = "<div>{{TitleFlag}}</div>";
$scope.trustedHtml = $interpolate($scope.HtmlContent)($scope);
$scope.TitleFlagToggle = function(){
    $scope.TitleFlag= !$scope.TitleFlag;
  };
```

And this is my view code:

```
<div>{{TitleFlag}}</div> <!-- This is update correctly -->
<div ng-bind-html="trustedHtml"></div> <!-- This is not update -->
<button class="button" ng-click="TitleFlagToggle()"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

While the TitleFlag is changing we need to interpolate it. So put the $scope.trustedHtml also in click function too.

```
$scope.TitleFlag= true;
$scope.HtmlContent = "<div>{{TitleFlag}}</div>";
$scope.trustedHtml = $interpolate($scope.HtmlContent)(  $scope);
$scope.TitleFlagToggle = function(){
  $scope.TitleFlag= !$scope.TitleFlag;
  $scope.trustedHtml = $interpolate($scope.HtmlContent)(  $scope);
};
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/rRjHOY2xSiAZ8EtzviqK?p=preview