# Send html content with variables to template from controller AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, carousel, ng-bind-html, ng-bind, ui.bootstrap

After being searching for this issue for a long time, I decided to do my first question in StackOverflow. I hope anyone can help me.

I'm doing a ui.bootstrap.carousel with different slides. The initial structure is the following :

```
    <carousel interval="carInterval" no-pause="true">
      <slide>
        some html content, {{ modules }}
      </slide>
      <slide>
        totally different content, {{ more variables }}
      </slide>
    </carousel>
```

That worked really well at the start,  even without using ng-repeat and any active statement. The problem started when I wanted to set a custom goToSlide() buttons. Looking around I just found that I can do it only using the ng-repeat syntax (the normal and given by bootstrap). When I tried to do it in this way, I have to declare all the content of the slides in the javascript file.

```
    angular.module('anyApp')
      .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.anyModule="Anything"
        $scope.slider=[]
        $scope.slider.push({ content: " \
            <h1> html content {{ anyModule }} </h1> \
            "});
      });
```

Then, in the html:

```
    <carousel interval="myInterval" no-wrap="noWrapSlides">
       <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
         <p ng-bind-html="slide.content"> </p>
       </slide>
    </carousel>
```

The html content appears well but the variables don't appear. I tried also this:

```
$scope.slider.push({ content: " \
    <h1> html content <p ng-bind-template='{{ anyModule }} '></p></h1> "});
```

If you know any possible solution for this problem or maybe just set and an active slider that is not in ng-repeat syntax, I would appreciate it so much.

Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should use $interpolate not $compile.** $interpolate returns a string, which is what $scope.anyModule needs to be in this case; $compile returns a DOM element.

check this: [AngularJS data bind in ng-bind-html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796102/angularjs-data-bind-in-ng-bind-html)

Comment: I also solved this issue doing a directive to compile the DOM, as i found in this reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157305/angularjs-compiling-dynamic-html-strings-from-database