# $interpolate values from a ng-repeat created scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-bind-html, angularjs-interpolate

A follow up to this question: [AngularJS data bind in ng-bind-html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796102/angularjs-data-bind-in-ng-bind-html)

What if the values which I want to interpolate are attached to a ng-repeat created scope?

```
myDict = {'Suggestion' : $interpolate('Vote here if you think {{player.name}} is right!')($scope) 
          ...};// $scope is wrongly passed here as 'player' is not a scope variable,
```

And then

`<div ng-repeat="player in players">
    <span ng-bind-html="myDict['Suggestion']"></span>
</div>`

Is it possible to do such a thing without a custom directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thankfully, you're the one deciding when you call the function:

```
$scope.myDict = function (scope) {
  return {'Suggestion' : $interpolate('Vote here if you think {{player.name}} is right!')(scope);
}
```

Then in your HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="player in players">
    <span ng-bind-html="myDict({player: player})['Suggestion']"></span>
</div>
```

This will call the function once per player with an object literal, and pass this as the "scope" for the `$interpolate` call.

---

Be warned, however: if you have thousands of records, calling a function everytime might have some sort of perf. hit. The only way around it I can think of is using `{{players[$index].name}}` in the `$interpolate` call...