# How to bind HTML to an Element - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to bind html to my div element, but dont really know how to do it. I am not great with angularjs, but should `ng-bind-html` do the trick?

This is how I tried to do it,

```
<div ng-bind-html="{{tile.Info.Title}}"></div>
<div ng-bind-html="{{tile.Info.Content}}"></div>
```

In angular 2 its just `[innerHTML]`, cant get it to work here, any suggestion?

Comment: general rule: if it has `ng-`, then you don't need curly brackets `{{ ... }}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS data bind in ng-bind-html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796102/angularjs-data-bind-in-ng-bind-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As also suggested in comments by @Aleksey when you are using `ng-` there is no need to use curly brackets `{}`. So your code should be like:

```
<div ng-bind-html="tile.Info.Title"></div>
<div ng-bind-html="tile.Info.Content"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get an example [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml).

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
 <p ng-bind-html="myHTML"></p>
</div>
```