# rending html text in table <td> in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html-table

I have below table structure and I am trying to bind this table with data returned by API/web service result.
`
         
          
            
              
               Id
              
              
               Tracking
             
            
          
          
            
               
                {{ticket.Id}}

```
          <td>
            {{ticket.Tracking}}
          </td>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>  
    </div>
```

The field ticket.Tracking is having value "abc <br>xyz<br>test<html<br>". but web page its displaying like below 
"abc <br>xyz<br>test<html<br>"
but I want to render this test like below

abc
xyz
test
html

How can I achieve it in angularJS. Thanks a lots in advance.

Comment: Please describe for clearly.

Comment: can you add controller and HTML both codes?

Comment: Have you tried `ng-bind-html`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS data bind in ng-bind-html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796102/angularjs-data-bind-in-ng-bind-html)

Comment: Dear use this structure for displaying data in new line then use ul-li structure inside your e.g.: <table><tr><td><ul><li></li></ul></td></tr></table>