# AngularJS - Using interpolation in a html template

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Not sure if anyone has come across this situation before, looking up on google I cant seem to find examples. Bascially I am creating a lenghty html template and i wrap it in a ng-bing-html, it loads my html but it dosent load my interpolation. Let me give you a quick example:

**Controller:**

```
$scope.example_text_here = "Hello World!"
$scope.HTML_template = "<p><strong> Example: </strong> {{ example_text_here }}</p>"
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-bind-html="HTML_template"></div>
```

**Output**

> **Example:** {{ example_text_here }}

**What I am expecting:**

> **Example:** Hello world!

Anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS data bind in ng-bind-html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796102/angularjs-data-bind-in-ng-bind-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use $interpolate module and then injecting current scope or even $compile. See more https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate

```
$interpolate($scope.HTML_template)($scope)
```

Comment: Ah this is new to me, very intersting function. Seems to work so far. Thank you so much!.

Comment: One small thing tough, the ng-bind-html do not seem to work. Looking this up but would you know what the proper way of doing it with $interpolate?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$scope.HTML_template = "<p><strong> Example: 
 </strong>"+$scope.example_text_here+"</p>";
```

Comment: Thanks but I have an ng-repeat in there also, dont think this will work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd use `$sce` service of **AngularJS**.

**Controller:**

```
angular.module('app', [...])

.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $sce) {
  ...
  $scope.trustAsHtml = function(params) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(params);
  };
  ...
  $scope.example_text_here = "Hello World!";
  $scope.HTML_template = "<p><strong> Example: </strong> {{ example_text_here }}</p>";
  ...
});
```

**Markup:**

```
<div ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml(HTML_template)"></div>
```

Now hope you'd get your *expected* result. Thanks.

Comment: Ill give this a try.

Comment: Gives the same result {{ example_text_here }}