# Getting ng-repeat to work inside of AngularJS's $interpolate service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the AngularJs-UI components for Bootstrap. I would like to insert a filled out template into one of the data elements for the popover feature. This works find for all elements not inside of a ng-repeat.  How do I get the ng-repeat elements to work inside of a interpolated template?

I have a plunker at http://plnkr.co/edit/Cuku7qaUTL1lxRkafKzv Its not working because I don't know how to get Angular-UI-bootstrap to in plunker.

```
<div data-popover="{{createHTML()}}">some content</div>
```

My local scope has the function `createHTML()` that looks something like this.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize'])
  .controller("myController", function(myService){
    $scope.createHTML = function() {
      var thingy = { blah: "foobar", collection: [ "1", "2", "3" ] };
      return myService.html_for(thingy);
    }
  });
```

And the service is

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .service('myService', function($templateCache, $interpolate, $sanitize, $log) {
    "use strict";

    function html_for(thingy) {
      var template = $templateCache.get('thingyTemplate.html'),
        link = $interpolate(template),
        html = link(thingy),
        unsafe = $sanitize(html);
      return unsafe;
    }

    return {
      html_for: html_for
    }
  });
```

Templates:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="thingyTemplate.html">
  <div>
    <div><strong>Blah:</strong> {{blah}}</div>
    <div data-ng-repeat="foo in collection"><strong>Collection:</strong> {{foo}}</div>
    <div><strong>Collection[0]:</strong> {{collection[0]}}</div>
    <div><strong>Collection[1]:</strong> {{collection[1]}}</div>
    <div><strong>Collection[2]:</strong> {{collection[2]}}</div>
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="template/popover/popover.html">
<div class="popover {{placement}}" data-ng-class="{ in: isOpen(), fade: animation() }">
  <div class="arrow"></div>

  <div class="popover-inner">
    <h3 class="popover-title" data-ng-bind="title" data-ng-show="title"></h3>
    <div class="popover-content" data-ng-bind-html="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`$interpolate` doesn't handle directives like `ngRepeat` (
[Difference between parse, interpolate and compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900588/what-is-the-difference-between-the-parse-interpolate-and-compile-services) ).  [`$interpolate`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$interpolate):

> Compiles a string with markup into an interpolation function. This
>   service is used by the HTML $compile service for data binding.

To handle `ngRepeat` and other directives you want [`$compile`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile).  But for your use case `$compile` is going to result, unfortunately, in a number of changes because:

- It needs a scope to compile against rather than just a context like `$interpolate`.  Moreover it needs the scope `thingy` is on.

  This means we'll need to reference your properties like so {{thingy.blah}} instead of {{blah}} inside your template.
- The compile needs to happen when the popup is on the dom.
- The popup is only on the dom when it's open.

So we can't just replace `$interpolate` with `$compile` inside your service.

One approach is to replace `data-ng-bind-html` with the following directive that acts like an `ng-bind-html` that has a built in `$compile` (clearly you should only use this with html that you know is safe).

```
.directive('compile', function($compile) {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(
      function(scope) {
        return scope.$eval(attrs.compile);
      },
      function(value) {
        var result = element.html(value);
        $compile(element.contents())(scope.$parent.$parent);
      }
    );
  };
});
```

Used like so (with `compile` replacing `ng-bind-html`:

```
  <div class="popover-content" compile="content"></div>
```

One issue is that we need `thingy` to be in scope.  There's a few of ways of handling that- but for demonstration purposes I've manually gone back up to the scope the popover is called from - which is 2 scopes up thus the `scope.$parent.$parent`.

Using this compile directive you no longer `$interpolate` or `$sanitize`so the function in your service can shrink down to just returning the appropriate template:

```
function html_for() {
  var template = $templateCache.get('thingyTemplate.html');
  return template;
}
```

<kbd>[**demo fiddle**](http://plnkr.co/edit/2jY0NEX2tMVYB8qSIrXO?p=preview)</kbd>