# AngularJS - ngRepeat - override html rendering

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

i have the following ng-repeat code:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</div>
```

is there a way to programatically get into a javascript variable the 'final' html output of each of the repeated items instead of rendering it on the page?

hope that's clear enough.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Geting ng-repeat to work inside of AngularJS's $interpolate service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20911214/geting-ng-repeat-to-work-inside-of-angularjss-interpolate-service)

Comment: What does that mean "'final' html output"? Do you want to store the HTML of interpolated `{{item}}`?

Comment: yes, store it and prevent it from being rendered on the page. but i think the best thing i can do is to implement a custom element -like- ngRepeat.