# In what contexts is interpolation legal in Angular, and why?

Tags: html, angularjs

I know that Angular's string interpolation normally operates on expressions inside Handlebars-style `{{ double curly braces }}`, and by observation I know that I can use it in contexts like

- text outside HTML tags: `<span>{{ 'string literal expression ' }}</span>`
- attribute values inside HTML tags: `<a href="{{ '/link/to/somewhere' }}">link</a>`

and not to generate attributes themselves, i.e.

- `<a {{ 'href="/link/to/elsewhere"' }}>link</a>`

does not get interpolated.

What I'm curious about is why: what are the rules on where interpolation does and doesn't happen, where this is documented, and what the design considerations or constraints are that led to this.

I guess this is because the document is parsed as HTML by the browser before Angular sees it, so the structure is dictated by HTML and the `{{ stuff }}` has to appear in places that are well-formed according to HTML even before interpolation happens. But I'd appreciate knowing the whole story.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### What are the rules on where interpolation does and doesn't happen ?

Angular.js uses $compile service to compile a piece of DOM. [The docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile) says:

> The compilation is a process of walking the DOM tree and matching DOM elements to directives.

In the source code of [compile.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/02a45826f12842a5eec07989264abbe42b381a7c/src/ng/compile.js) there is a function `collectDirectives`, I trimmed it to show only the relevant code:

```js
function collectDirectives(node, directives, attrs, maxPriority, ignoreDirective) {
  var nodeType = node.nodeType;
  // ....
  switch(nodeType) {
    case 1: /* Element */

      // ....

      // iterate over the attributes
      for (var attr, name, nName, ngAttrName, value, nAttrs = node.attributes,
               j = 0, jj = nAttrs && nAttrs.length; j < jj; j++) {          
        // ....
          addAttrInterpolateDirective(node, directives, value, nName);
        // ....
      }

      // ....
      break;
    case 3: /* Text Node */
      addTextInterpolateDirective(directives, node.nodeValue);
      break;
    case 8: /* Comment */
      // ....
      break;
  }

  directives.sort(byPriority);
  return directives;
}
```

As you can see, $compile search for interpolated content only inside **attributes** and **text nodes** when it iterates a piece of DOM.

Those functions, `addTextInterpolateDirective` *and* `addAttrInterpolateDirective` **"translate"** the interpolated expression into directives that $watch interpolated expressions and update the DOM element.

#### Where this is documented?

The compilation phase is documented here: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler

It's getting better every day but still some in-depth stuff are not clear until you read the source code itself. I guess some things are just too compilcated to explain without showing the code.

#### What the design considerations or constraints are that led to this?

I guess there are two reasons:

- `Angular operates on DOM nodes rather than strings`, If angular needed to interpolate attributes or elements then It should operate on **html strings** which is probably bad for performance.
- There is no major use case for such things.

#### If you still want to interpolate everything, do that kind of magic inside a directive:

An [example](http://jsbin.com/AqADOWop/1/edit):

```
app.directive('myAnchor',function(){
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    transclude: true,
    link: function(scope,element,attrs,ctrl,$transclude) {

      attrs.$observe('interpolate', function(val){   
        var e = angular.element("<a " + val + "></a>");
        $transclude(scope,function(clone){
           e.append(clone);
        });
        element.replaceWith(e);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

#### Be sure to read this:

[What is the difference between the $parse, $interpolate and $compile services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900588/what-is-the-difference-between-the-parse-interpolate-and-compile-services)