# AngularJS, inline filter for appended html

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to do something similar to the following:  [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DWQ1kc5fRSg1KHqUAoBt?p=preview)

I know that i can use `$filter` service but I think that inline filtering is more expressive.

If anyone can take a look at link above and tell me where is my mistake.

Edit(using $interpolate): [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DWQ1kc5fRSg1KHqUAoBt?p=preview)

I'm not sure If I'v used `$interpolate` the right way but as you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900588/what-is-the-difference-between-the-parse-interpolate-and-compile-services) I think I did.

Comment: Have you looked at the `$interpolate` provider? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate

Comment: I tried it, let me edit to show you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my guess is that Angular has no knowledge of the template, you need to manually compile it or preferably, use the template key when creating the directive.

I modified your snippet [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Okm87BWEdLOigaUXcwA2?p=preview), but basically it boils down to:

```
mainApp.directive('mainContainer', function($parse){
  return {
    template: '<h1>{{ lowerString | CapFirst }}</h1>',
    link: function(scope, elem) {
      scope.lowerString = 'lol';
    }
  };
});
```

## Edit

As requested, here is an alternative [snippet](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xnn9FSHXE1kPjBYvWDD7?p=preview) that uses the `$compile` service:

```
mainApp.directive('mainContainer', function($compile){
  return function(scope, elem) {
    var lowerString = 'lol';
    var html = $compile('<h1>{{ "' + lowerString + '" | CapFirst }}</h1>')(scope);
    elem.append(html);
  };
});
```

This could also work if you used `$interpolate` instead of `$compile`. The benefit of using `$compile` is that if you were using a template with bindings to the scope, `$compile` would properly bind the scope to the template, whereas `$interpolate` would not.

Comment: Thank you, I think I will use your way, but can you show me how to compile it manually?

Comment: @AvielFadida I updated it with an alternative method which does the same thing but is a little more messy!