# Angular: using transclude with ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, transclusion, ng-bind-html

I have the following **angular** setup:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.filter('unsafe', function($sce) {
  return $sce.trustAsHtml;
});

app.controller('SearchController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.searchString = '';
  $scope.searchType = 'Artist';
  $scope.updateHtml = function() {
    $http.get('/search', {
      params: {
        searchString: $scope.searchString,
        searchType: $scope.searchType
      }
    }).success(function(data) {
      $scope.html = data;
    }).error(function(err){
      $scope.html = err;
    });
  };
  $scope.updateHtml(); 
}]);

app.directive('searchDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div ng-bind-html="html | unsafe" ng-transclude></div>'
  };
});
```

It pulls raw html markup through ajax in the controller and stores it in `@scope.html`. In the directive, this html is inserted into the DOM through `ng-bind-html`.

The **html** (jade) looks as follows:

```
#search(ng-controller="SearchController" search-directive)
```

It basically works. But inside this html that is included, i have some transclusive content, like `{{searchType}}` that i want to be resolved. Unfortunatly, that is not the case, it shows "{{searchType}}" in the browser. What can i change to make the transclusion work?

I read about `$compile` and `$transclude`, but i don't know how to use it or if it can help me solve my issue. thx!

Comment: $interpolate the html before setting it to $scope.html in the controller. See answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796102/angularjs-data-bind-in-ng-bind-html

Comment: great, $interpolate does the trick! thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with the help of Patrick, i was able to solve it. i changed my controller to

```
 app.controller('SearchController', ['$scope', '$http', '$interpolate',  
              function($scope, $http, $interpolate) {
    $scope.searchString = '';
    $scope.searchType = 'Artist';
    $scope.updateHtml = function() {
      $http.get('/search', {
        params: {
          searchString: $scope.searchString,
          searchType: $scope.searchType
        }
      }).success(function(data) {
        $scope.html = $interpolate(data)($scope); // <<-- difference here
      }).error(function(err){
        $scope.html = err;
      });
    };
    $scope.updateHtml(); 
  }]);
```

and now my html is interpolated based on the passed-in scope. thank you!

**edit:** 
`$interpolate` is only for rendering the DOM and parsing it through the scope. it simply returns plain html. if you need to actually retrieve a full working html template, with angular code in it, use `$compile`. i found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900588/what-is-the-difference-between-the-parse-interpolate-and-compile-services) extremely helpful in sorting out the differences between `$interpolate`, `$compile` and `$parse`.