# How to add some HTML code to the DOM with angularJS templates and make AngularJS to interpolate them?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-interpolate

I have some some service. I wanna to debug it and see state of variables in this service. My code is below (explanation below the code):

```
module.factory('Data', function () {
    var current = [], unlocked = [], all = [];

    return {
        current: current,
        unlocked: unlocked,
        total: all
    }
});
module.controller('debugPlaneController', ['$scope', 'Data', function ($scope, data) {
    $scope.data = data;
}]);
module.factory('someService', ['Data', function (data) {
    var initDebugMode = function () {
        var style = "style='width: 500px; height: 100px; background-color: #ccc;";
        var template = "
            <div "+style+" ng-controller='debugPlaneController'>
                <p>data.current = {{ data.current }}</p>
                <p>data.total = {{ data.total }}</p>
                <p>data.unlocked= {{ data.unlocked }}</p>
            </div>
        ";
        $(".someClass > .childClassOfSomeClass").append(template);
    };
    // some more methods, for example
    var push = function (name) {
        data.current.push(name);
        data.all.push(name);
    }
    // etc
    return {
        initDebug: initDebugMode,
        push: push
        // some more methods
    }
}]);

module.controller('mainController', ['$scope', 'someService', function($scope, someService) {
    someService.initDebug();
    someService.push('lala');
});
```

So, I have some app with controller `mainController`. I want to use service `someService` in it. I am using `push` method. This method pushes data from `name` argument to `total` and `current` arrays of Data service `Data`. As you see, I called method `initDebug()` from `mainController`, so I want debug window to appear on my screen. I want to show state of arrays `current`, `total` and `unlocked` of `Data` data-service.

Actually, window appears on screen, but I see this on it:

```
data.current = {{ data.current }}
data.total = {{ data.total }}
data.all = {{ data.all }}
```

So, AngularJS templates wasn't interpolated. How I can make them interpolating + I need live update of them in this block (like angularJS actually do).

### Update

Using $compile.

So I need to change my `initDebugMode` function this way?:

```
module.factory('someService', ['Data', '$compile', function (data, $compile) {
    var initDebugMode = function () {
        var style = "style='width: 500px; height: 100px; background-color: #ccc;";
        var scopeImitation = { data: data };

        var template = "
            <div "+style+" ng-controller='debugPlaneController'>
                <p>data.current = {{ data.current }}</p>
                <p>data.total = {{ data.total }}</p>
                <p>data.unlocked= {{ data.unlocked }}</p>
            </div>
        ";
        $compile(template)(scopeImitation);
        $(".someClass > .childClassOfSomeClass").append(template);
    };
// etc...
]);
```

How exactly passing variable to 2nd brackets in `$compile` service works? I used this correctly?

Comment: Use the `$compile` service to compile dynamic HTML against the `$scope`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the $compile service:

## $compile

> Compiles an HTML string or DOM into a template and produces a template function, which can then be used to link scope and the template together.

You would use it like:

```
$compile(template)($scope);
```

Don't forget to inject the `$compile` service and `$scope` into your factory first though.

I would also read through this post to understand the other angular services you could use to achieve your goals:

[What is the difference between the $parse, $interpolate and $compile services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900588/what-is-the-difference-between-the-parse-interpolate-and-compile-services)

Because `$interpolate` might be more suited to what you're trying to do, but `$compile` is the most powerful.

---

## Regarding your edit

At first I didn't really take proper notice of the fact that you were inside a factory. I think it is generally inadvisable (maybe impossible?) to pass the scope into into the factory. If you want a reuseable debug interface, I think the best way would not to be putting it in your factory, but instead, making a directive:

```
module.directive('debug' , function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template:'<div><p>data.current = {{ data.current }}</p><p>data.total = {{ data.total }}</p><p>data.unlocked= {{ data.unlocked }}</p></div>',
        controller: 'debugPlaneController'
    }
});
```

I removed the `style` from your template because you can actually style the directive from your css by defining a css rule for `debug`

```
debug > div {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

And I removed `ng-controller` from your template because your directive will use the controller defined in the directive.

Now you can put your directive wherever you want like this. It'll generate the template inside correctly without you having to worry about $compile:

```
<debug></debug>
```

Moreover if you want to only show it conditionally you could use `ng-if`

```
<debug ng-if="debugMode == true"></debug> //debugMode would be a variable you defined in your controller
```

Also regarding your question for `$compile` and your `scopeImitation` I've never seen it used that way before and I don't think that would work. `$compile` from what I've seen is always written as `$compile(thing to compile)($scope)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated my answer, check it please. Did I used 2nd parameter of compile service correctly? How exactly this works? Or should I inject $scope in factroy `someService` too? And pass this `$scope` to the `$compile`? But will it be such scope as `debugPlaneController` has? Explain this please in your answer.

Comment: Or will this will just bind properties in 2nd argument object with teamplates in HTML code?

Comment: I'm updating my answer, and it'll answer your questions hopefully.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav take a look at it now.

Comment: If I will use directive what scope will be used to get value of `data.current`? Current values of `debugPlaneController`'s scope?